# Converting date to proper format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in an ms-sql database which contains dates in a column like so:

```
2010-06-24 00:00:00.000
```

Then in c#, I get those dates w/ a statement and assign it to a variable which populates a column of a grid on a web page made w/ asp.net.

```
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            //connection info here
            sql2 = "(select statement here);
            command.CommandText = sql2;
            dates["Entry"] = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

So, this fills up the grid w/ the correct dates, however, I'm trying to format it so I just get the month, day, and year, not the time after, with slashes. So like this:

```
06/24/2010
```

I've tried converting it to date time and using:

```
ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

I've tried using a reader instead and doing something like:

```
reader.GetDatetime.toString("MM/dd/yyy")
```

which also didn't work. I just can't seem to find the correct way to do this. Any tips would be great.

Edit: Here's the sql2 statement:

```
sql2 = "select max(day) as day from users u join days d on d.User_ID = u.id where u.ActiveUser = 1 and u.id = " + Users["ID"].ToString();
```

This is just getting the most recent date a user has entered stuff in.

Edit 2:
The date that shows up in the grid is like so "3/12/2013 12:00:00 AM".

Edit 3: The .ExecuteScalar() function seems to be formatting the date automatically to "3/12/2013 12:00:00 AM" type of format.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your format to `yyyy-MM-dd` like;

```
dates["Entry"] = ((DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: May I ask what cultureinfo is? That's not valid when I try to use it.

Comment: @pfinferno Oh right, `ExecuteScalar` returns `object`. I assumed your column type you return is mapped with `DateTime` on CLR side, you need to get _textual_ representation of your `DateTime`. `InvariantCulture` is for guaranteed to generate Gregorian Calendar representation of your `DateTime` value.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for the response! I tried what you did, and similar things earlier. I'm getting this error though "InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code." - Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @pfinferno What is the type of first column that returned by your select statement?

Comment: Do you mean the column in the SQL table? When I go to properties of the column itself, it says Data Type = datetime, System Type = datetime, Identity = False, and a bunch of other stuff like primary key, allow nulls, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry...don't understand what you mean. I posted the sql2 statement in my post.

Comment: @pfinferno What is the type of `day` column?

Comment: @pfinferno If it is _really_ `datetime`, my code should work.

Comment: Hmm, yeah it's still giving a cast exception. Besides right clicking and getting the properties for the column, I also ran a query to get the data_type of the column which also returned "datetime".

Comment: Please see the last edit on bottom of post. Might be a clue.

Answer (score 0):

2010-06-24  If you want to display a DateTime like this you just pass a format string of "yyyy-mm-dd" so it would look like this:

```
string Date = new DateTime(2010, 6, 24).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

You can read more about what formats you can output on a DateTime at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ToShortDateString() function to cut off the time string-:

```
reader.GetDatetime.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out following in the sql:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, column_name, 101) from table_name
```

101 - is datetime style. You may find all styles by the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx)

Also in code behind:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(reader["column"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Hope it helps