# Issues converting strings to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in an ms-sql database which contains dates in a column like so:

```
2012-10-31 00:00:00.000
```

This column is listed as type 'datetime'. As in, in ms sql server management studio, I expand the table, then columns, and see the Dates(PK, datetime, not null).

Then in c#, I get those dates w/ a statement and assign it to a variable which populates a column of a grid on a web page made w/ asp.net. The sql statement is just getting the last entry of a user.

```
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        //connection info here
        sql2 = "select max(day) as day from users u join days d on d.User_ID = u.id where u.ActiveUser = 1 and u.id = " + Users["ID"].ToString();;
        command.CommandText = sql2;
        dates["Entry"] = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

This populates the dates in the column like so:

```
10/31/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Now, I have no idea why it's getting converted like that. I was following the data while be debugging and it changes w/ the command.ExecuteScalar() function. The format I would like to have is:

```
10/31/2012
```

without the hh/mm/ss AM.

I could not get ANY DateTime conversions/parses/formatting to work properly. I've spent four days on this. I asked a similar question here: [Converting date to proper format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073725/converting-date-to-proper-format) , trying all the different suggestions.

What I'm doing in the meantime is:

```
string dt = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
dt = dt.Substring(0, dt.IndexOf(" ") + 1); 
dates["Entry"] = dt;
```

Which gets rid of all the text after the space in the date string that was returned. This would be okay, except that I wanted to compare these dates I'm getting, so I need them in DateTime. Trying to convert these strings to DateTime just would not work.

Edit: Definitions and types -

```
DataRow dates;
//for loop here going through for each user
dates = _dtuserhours.NewRow(); // _dtuserhours is a DataTable
//Sql statements here
_dtuserhours = new DataTable("newtable");
DataColumn column;
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "Entry";
_dtUserHours.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: have you tried using date as the column data type instead of datetime?

Comment: Good suggestion but I can't change anything w/ the database. I'm allowed to get whatever from it to read, but nothing to modify it.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to change your SQL string to use command parameters, otherwise you are open to a SQL Injection attack.

Next, You can shape the output of your DateTime field in SQL Server to output the format you are looking for.  What you are getting is the default format for DateTime depending on your culture.

Or, you could easily just use the string formatter property of the DateTime object that is returned like this:

```
dates["Entry"] = ((DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

EDIT:  Try this instead:

```
dynamic result = command.ExecuteScalar();
dates["Entry"] = result.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

EDIT of the EDIT - set to dynamic because the compiler doesn't know what ExecuteScalar is returning at compile time.

Comment: I will definitely put in parameters. Someone suggested the string formatter property on my other question before, but this is the error I get "InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code. Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: What is the data type of the day column in the database?

Comment: Right clicking on it and going to properties, it says Data Type is datetime. All lowercase.

Comment: if you put the result in a variable and check the type with reflection, what does it return?  Are you showing us ALL of your code?

Comment: If I add a string variable = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), the value is equal to "10/31/2012 12:00:00 AM". However, the dates["Entry"] value is empty and the type is System.DBNull. I have showed all my code.

Comment: do this:

    var value = command.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine(value.GetType().FullName);

Post the results here.

Comment: System.DateTime. The Value of 'value' contains 10/20/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: What is your datatype on dates["Entry"] ??

Comment: It is a System.Data.DataRow

Comment: So the "Entry" column is a datarow?  Is dates a DataSet?  If "Entry" is a column of a DataTable, then you need to tell us the type you have declared for the column

Comment: I'll edit the bottom of my post to include all declarations.

Comment: Apparently I can't use 'dynamic'. Says I'm missing the reference but I'm using Microsoft.CSharp at the top.

Comment: Unfortunately it requires targeting the 4.0 framework. I'm targeting 3.5 right now, but can't change it due to the way things are done in other areas of the code. This is an old project that's been worked on by a lot of people.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems getting .Net to convert the date to the exact format you want, you can always convert it to a formatted string in the SQL instead.

See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php for a list of the formats available and how to use them. In this case it'd be something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, max(day), 101) AS day 
FROM users u JOIN days d ON d.User_ID = u.id 
WHERE {etc, and parameterise your query!}
```

Comment: I've tried this using the '101' value for the mm/dd/yyyy but was unsure how to add this into my sql statement, or if I needed a new statement completely? (very new to sql)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToShortDateString` on the result should give you the date in the desired format:

```
dates["Entry"] = ((DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar()).ToShortDateString()
```

For this to work as expected, you will need to change the data type for column `dates["Entry"]` to `DateTime`:

```
column.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
```

Comment: Same problem as the answer below, giving an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @pfinferno Most likely, the issue is with the definition of `dates`. Please post how `dates` is defined

Comment: I think you and sharp ninja are on to it. dates is defined as DataRow dates;

Comment: Getting an InvalidCastException again when doing that :/

Answer (score 1):

So you have two issues :

1) Show the Date time column in a specific format : (i.e MM/dd/yyyy)

2) Use This Column For Datetime comparison also.

**Here are two Approaches :**

A) **Have two columns** (not a good way of solving things but gets work done) in your datatable.

i. One column for display (which will be of datatype string which you have made above).

ii. Another column with DateTime datatype for comparing.

**B) Manipulate a single DateTime Column**

i. From What I see, Entry Date has a datatype string, change it to datetime & fill it without any string conversion via the Executescalar.

ii. Wherever you are displaying EntryDate column, make an inplace conversion using toString("MM/dd/yyyy") method.

iii. Wherever you are Comparing, just cast it to Datetime & compare.